# What's the consequence of breaking fast after ekadashi parana?

Tags: fasting, ekadashi

I fasted for Shravana Putrada Ekadashi yesterday and unfortunately, I broke the fast 30 minutes **after** parana, but still on dwadashi day. According to drikpanchang, parana was from 07:41 AM to 08:52 AM. I broke the fast at 9:15 am. What's the consequence, if any, of committing this mistake and what are the remedial measures, if any?

Comment: by drikpanchag you mean this site https://www.drikpanchang.com ?

Comment: @Rishabh Yes. It's a great site.